# Rails call comment box with jquery on single posts in a index page where all posts are listed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook, comments

I have a list of posts in my index file.  On every post i want to have comments.  I have a button called show comment on every post. When i press show comment, i want jquery to trigger that comment box on the particular post.

The problem now is, I trigger alle the show comments on the whole page.

Here is my code:

I think the problem is in the script.

```
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="span6">
  <h4><%= post.title %></h4>
  <p><%= post.text %></p>
   <p><%= link_to "Go to", post_path(post) %></p>

<button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary comments-show-button"  type="button">Show comments</button>
        <button id="remove-button" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" type="button">Remove comments</button>
    <div class="comments">
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="430"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
<% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".comments-show-button").click(function(){
$(".comments").show(500);
$("#remove-button").show(500);
 $(".comments-show-button").hide();
 });
$(".comments").mouseout(function(){
$("#comments-show-button").hide();
 });

});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comments-show-button").click(function() {
        var $thisPost = $(this).closest('div.span6');
        var $comments = $thisPost.find('div.comments');
        $comments.show(500);
        $thisPost.find("#remove-button").show(500);
        $thisPost.find(".comments-show-button").hide();
    });
    $(".comments").mouseout(function(){
        $("#comments-show-button").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: That is awesome, thanks for your help. Im gonna use this a lot future on, in my app :)

Comment: Next i am trying to make a function. When i hit the remove button, the comments diapear and the show button comes back. Still only on a single posts.     But u can't make it work. It is only on the first post it works

Comment: That's because your `#remove_button` is using an **ID** and not a **class**. You are only allowed to have a single unique ID per page. change that to a class and it'll work.